# How to change the background color of an Android View

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, view, android-widget

I have made a customView like this

```
class MyCustomView extends View {

    public MyCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }               
}
```

and I have used this inside a layout and given property to set it height to WRAP_CONTENT, but on UI this is covering the entire screen? Why it happen so? What make it to be full screen?

And too when I go for setBackgroundColor() , its not working

Comment: I don't understand the point of `MyCustomView`. It doesn't do anything. Is there additional implementations you are not showing?

Comment: @Jason Robinson yeah I do have additional things within this view..anyhow even if the view is empty..then too the view will fill the entire screen??...y is it so...it doesnt have anythng rite!! even I cant set the background color of it

Comment: You've probably implemented something wrong in `MyCustomView`. Can you show the whole source for that?